# how to bind an exe to a gui button - kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Allright, I just wrote a programme specific for my data analysis purposes and convert it to exe and when i double click on it, it works fine now except showing the console and all the other things it is doing. Instead double clicking on the exe file, i developped a very simple kivy gui which is as follows;

```
from cProfile import label
from email.mime import image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class Data_Col(App):
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
        self.window.size_hint = (0.5, 0.5)
        self.window.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y" : 0.5}
        # add widgets to window

        # image widget
        self.window.add_widget(Image(source="logo.png"))
        # label widget
        self.greeting = Label(text="Bonjour!!!", font_size = 18, bold = True)
        self.window.add_widget(self.greeting)
        # button widget
        self.button = Button(text="Run Data-Col", size_hint = (0.3, 0.3), bold = True, background_color = '0175E8', background_normal = "")
        self.window.add_widget(self.button)
        
        
        return self.window

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Data_Col().run()
```

what i want is when the user clicks on the button, it runs the exe file which is in a different folder in my pc. So i need to give a path too to the button to go and tricks the execution of exe file. But don't know how to do it, if anyone knows i would appreciate it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Kivy, but I can help you run an .EXE file.

This is the code I wrote:

```
import os

def run_exe(file): # This is the function to run
    os.system("start "+file)

run_exe("path/to/file.exe") # Replace "path/to/file.exe" with the path to your file (E.G. "C:/Users/Hipposgrumm/Documents/helloworld.exe").
```

Hopefully, that works. I'm more of a TKinter user so tell me if this isn't usable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i need some more explanation. for example `def run_exe(path,file):` should i replace `path` with the location of my exe file and `file` with the name of the file? and following  here `os.system("start "+path+"/"+file)` should i also replace path and file too?

Comment: The `path` needs to be the path to the folder containing the EXE file, and `file` is the file name. I'll modify my answer to make it a bit more understandable.

Comment: unfortunately the code you wroteI coudn't bined with the button i am trying to bind. not working. If TKinter is more simple I can try that out. I don't have a slightest idea about guis, my friend told me to try out kivy.